# Openpyxl apply code to every cell in the column

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

HI hope you're doing great,
I'm a beginner in python
I need to write a **variable** instead of **Row number** and loop it from 1 - 500
to make the code run for every row in the excel file
is that possible ?!?! and another thing is that the file doesn't work when it's exported with the ".xlsx" extension it works only as the ".xls" extension
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kZm8.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> write a variable instead of Row number and loop it from 1 - 500 to
> make the code run for every row in the excel file

You can use the f-string for dynamic cell reference:

```
for f in files:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
    ws = wb['Sheet1']

    for row_number in range(1, 501): #  Includes 1 but does not include 501
        data_in_column_A = ws[f"A{row_number}"].value
        data_in_column_B = ws[f"B{row_number}"].value
        data_in_column_C = ws[f"C{row_number}"].value
```

The code above will iterate from row 1 to 500 and get data from the indicated column.